# Best practices for sending many emails at the same time or in a loop in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a rake task that loops through bookings and sends an email for each one using `.deliver` method (which I got from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OI-m0wbmf8A) (which I'm conscious **is now 7 years old**).

The problem is, sometimes some of the emails don't get sent. Here is my code

```rb
# Select bookings starting soon
bookings = Booking.where('start_time < ?', 24.hours.since)

# Email a reminder 
bookings.each do |booking|

  customer = booking.customer

  CustomerMailer.reminder_24h(customer, booking).deliver

end
```

Since the loop is in a rake task, I don't think there's any value in calling `.deliver_later`, so I just use `.deliver` like in the rails cast

I am curious to know if there are best practices that can help using Action Mailer, for example should there be a `sleep 2` between each email? Or should I always use `.deliver_later` to relieve the load on the server? Are there any other rails-related reasons that my code may not work (or, worse, I am using any anti patterns that I should refactor?)

TL;DR why would emails sent in a loop like in the code above occasionally fail to send

Comment: This says `.deliver` was deprecated a long time ago. I'm not sure why it has been working in this rails 6 application, but I'll switch all `.deliver` calls to `.deliver_now`. hopefully that helps. https://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery/deliver

Comment: You should always use `deliver_later` to enqueue email delivery as a job through Active Job (sidekiq, etc). It's highly unlikely that deliver_now is appropriate unless called on in a background job class.

Comment: @MarkMerritt thanks for the tip. I didn't think it would make a difference for a rake task. But I'll change it.

Comment: What are you using to deliver the emails, a local mail server or some 3rd party API?

Comment: @Eyeslandic I’m using the heroku sendgrid addon (so sendgrid is the mailing service)

Comment: Is there some kind of log you can view there to see why the emails are failing?

Comment: @Eyeslandic tbh I'm 90% sure the bug is in some complicated logic that determines which bookings to send emails for. But I just want to rule out any elementary errors I may be making. Regarding sendgrid, I can see everything it receives via the dashboard, and I don't see the emails that I expect to (the few that don't send). So I'm pretty sure it's either i) my logic, or ii) some mistakes in the methods used to send (e.g. perhaps not having things run as background jobs is causing trouble).

Answer (score 1):

No an answer, but some advice from another forum.

> Sending emails is a process that is filled with potential failures. It is always a good idea to do it in a background job that can be re-tried in case of intermittent errors like networks etc. and also skipped due to faulty addresses.

Here is a sketch of what may work:

```rb
# Reminder process rake task
namespace :bookings do
  desc "Deliver reminders to upcoming bookings"
  task remind_upcoming: :environment do
    EnqueueUpcomingBookingReminders.call(UpcomingBookingRemindersQuery.call)
  end
end
class EnqueueUpcomingBookingReminders
  def self.call(bookings_scope)
    booking_communication_attrs =
      bookings_scope
        .pluck(:id)
        .map { |id| {booking_id: id, type: "reminder"} }
    communications_result = 
      BookingCommunication.insert_all(booking_communication_attrs, unique_by: %i[booking_id type])
      # Email a reminder 
    communications_result.rows.flatten.each do |communication_id|
      DeliverBookingCommunicationJob.perform_later(communication_id)
    end
  end
end
class UpcomingBookingRemindersQuery
  def self.call(scope: Booking)
    Booking
      .upcoming_this_day
      .left_outer_joins(:communications)
      .merge(BookingCommunication.reminder)
      .where(communications: {id: nil})
  end
end
class Booking
  has_many :communications, class_name: "BookingCommunication"
  def self.upcoming_this_day
    where(starts_at:, (Time.current..24.hours.from_now))
  end
end
class BookingCommunication
  belongs_to :booking
  enum step: {confirmation: "confirmation", reminder: "reminder"} # combination of this and the booking id should be unique
  enum status: {pending: "pending", delivered: "delivered", canceled: "canceled", failed: "failed"} # should default to pending at database layer
end
class DeliverBookingCommunicationJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(communication_id)
    communication = BookingCommunication.find_by(communication_id)
    # Guard against state that invalidates us running this job
    return unless communication
    return unless communication.pending?
    return communication.canceled! if communication.booking.canceled? # This should probably live in the cancel booking process
    booking = communication.booking
    mailer = CustomerMailer.with(customer: booking.customer, booking: booking)
    case communication.step
    when "reminder"
      mailer.reminder_24h.deliver_now
    else
      # log unknown communication step, send to error tracking but dont raise since we do not want job to run again
    end
    communication.delivered!
  rescue SomeEmailRelatedError => err
    communication.failed!
    # deliver err to error tracking service
  end
end
```